# Sending camera video from browser to server

Tags: html, client-server, webcam, html5-video

Im trying out the new and exciting features of chrome canary 19.

I can basically grab the video from the web-cam and set it to a source element for a video tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Camera capture</title>
    <script>
        var localStream;
        var localStreamObjUrl;
        window.onload = function() {
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia("audio, video", gotStream);
        }
        function gotStream(stream) {
            localStream = stream;
            localStreamObjUrl = webkitURL.createObjectURL(localStream);
            var video = document.getElementById("selfView");
            video.src = localStreamObjUrl;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="selfView" autoplay audio=muted></video>
</body>
</html>
```

From the example at https://apprtc.appspot.com, we can grab the video and stream it to a peer...
 
My question is, can I avoid doing all the traversal to get a p2p connection and directly upload the video to a server? Id like to be able to relay the video stream instead of sending it p2p.

Comment: I'm interested to see if anyone has some insight into this.

Answer (score 6):

You need some kind of streaming media server on the back.

The process would be:

1. capture the feed
2. send it to the server
3. transcode to various client formats
4. manage the outbound streams

There are numerous free and paid varieties available:

- [nodejs(demo/POC)](http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/stream-a-webcam-using-javascript-nodejs-android-opera-mobile-web-sockets-and-html5/)
- [wowza(paid)](http://www.wowza.com/media-server/record)
- [chrome based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813875/how-do-i-capture-microphone-input-using-getusermedia-in-chrome-21)

More about transcoding: [xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler)
The 'swiss army knife' of media: [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html)

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed video recording solutions for the better part of the last 5 years and contributed a lot to fixing video recording bugs in Red5.

On the desktop you can use a Flash client + a media server (Red5, Wowza, Adobe Media Server) and on the mobile you can use HTML Media Capture.

I gave a detailed answer on a similar question at [Record video on browser and upload to LAMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343178/record-video-on-browser-and-upload-to-lamp-server/28696990#28696990)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [nimbb](https://www.nimbb.com/), in which they have Flash-based and HTML5 capturing.  After that, you can push the video to [Brightcove](http://www.brightcove.com/) to transcode it to various clients format.

They have API integration.  The only issue is the cost.