# How do I capture microphone input using getUserMedia in Chrome 21+?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

Chrome 21 was recently released, but I have not seen any working examples of getUserMedia for recording audio.

I've seen some nice examples for working with the webcam, but none that are able to record audio in a format that you could upload to a server:
http://neave.com/webcam/html5/

WebRTC is saying that recording in this way may not be possible yet, even with the Chrome update: 
http://www.webrtc.org/faq-recent-topics

I have had success using Flash to do this and save as an MP3, WAV, or OGG file. I've also found ways to do it in Java. I think doing it natively in the Browser would be amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this demo shows how to use it in opera/canary; its from march, and i think (from what you said) that it's now in chrome: http://creativejs.com/2012/03/getting-started-with-getusermedia/