# Stream realtime video between 2 computers using Python

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, flask, video-streaming

I am trying to **send my macbook air webcam video in realtime and receive it using python on another computer**. The motivation for this is to be able to offload realtime image recognition tasks to a server. The server requires having access to the realtime video frames in python so that I can then pass the frames to my image recognition algorithm (a deep neural net).

I was able to do this successfully using https://github.com/atuldo/videoStream
which uses the socket library to send the video frames in string format. However, this method results is a very low frame rate (see below for code snippet).

Attempt 1:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I also used this https://github.com/log0/video_streaming_with_flask_example which uses flask to stream the video to a web page. Looking at the webpage in chrome it has a much better frame rate than my first solution. However, this solution does not receive the video in python and would require me to read the video from the webpage, which I am not exactly sure how to go about.

Attempt 2 (I replaced pygame from original github code with cv2 to be able to access my mac webcam) :

```
### Server
import socket
from threading import *
import socket
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

import cv2

def server():
    #host_name = socket.gethostname()
    host_name = 'localhost'
    print "\nServer started at " + str(socket.gethostbyname(host_name)) + " at port " + str(90) 
    #port = 90
    port = 1024
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(("",port))
    serversocket.listen(10)
    #pygame.camera.init()
    #cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480),"RGB")
    #cam.start()
    #img = pygame.Surface((640,480))
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        connection, address = serversocket.accept()
        print "GOT_CONNECTION"
        #cam.get_image(img)
        #data = pygame.image.tostring(img,"RGB")
        success, image = video.read()
        data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
        connection.sendall(data)
        connection.close()

server()

###Reciever (snippet, for full code please refer to the github link above)

        clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        clientsocket.connect((self.ipAddress, self.port))
        received = []
        while True:
            recvd_data = clientsocket.recv(230400)
            if not recvd_data:
                break
            else:
                received.append(recvd_data)
        dataset = ''.join(received)
        #image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(640, 480),"RGB") # convert received image from string
        nparr = np.fromstring(dataset, np.uint8)
        image = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
        cv2.imwrite('foo.jpg', image)
        #pygame.image.save(image, "foo.jpg")
        self.ids.image_source.reload()
```

The video stream is displayed on the webpage like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
    <img id="bg" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get a high frame rate with either one of the two approaches or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate. See: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221876/sending-camera-video-from-browser-to-server)

Comment: I believe my question is more specific than the linked one. I actually asked this question after trying the answers in the question you linked to and finding the resulting frame rate too low. You’ll see I show ways to stream video in my question, which actually are based off the most up-voted answer in the linked question. My question as stated above is specific to getting a good frame rate so it will be useable for image recognition. Unfortunately there does not seem to be much info on doing this so far :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason may be that you `VideoCapture` device **is not configured for higher framerate** or it does not support higher framerate at all.

You specified *very low frame rate*, I don't know what this means to you, but I tested it with my 2 cameras. With slightly modified code, I can max out the first camera to 15fps, but the second one is running at 25fps without problems. These are expected numbers for me.